# Determine SMB vs FTP on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, smb

Our home network has both SMB shares (usually from windows 10 computers) and an FTP one (from our router). In Windows they pretty much look the same: you type `\\computerName` or `\\192.168.1.1` and pictures of folders come up with green tubes below them. Is there any way to determine whether these are shared via FTP or SMB? I'm looking for a quick GUI trick if one is available, but command line solutions are welcome as well.

**EDIT:** Turns out the router was advertised as being an FTP share only, but it must also be an SMB share according to the accepted answer. I'm leaving this question here for similarly confused people.

Comment: If you're accessing it with just `\\hostname` from Explorer, then it's not FTP.

Comment: I've never seen windows hide/reencode `ftp://server/folder/file.ext` urls as unc paths `\\server\share\file.ext`, but then again, I've never seen anyone try to hit ftp from windows explorer.

Comment: @FrankThomas Using ftp from Windows Explorer is a very effort-less task. When you need to do it, but you don't want to find a tool, just using Windows Explorer is comfortable and fast

Comment: Are you sure your router isn't also publishing an SMB share pointing at the same location as its FTP server? As Techie007 pointed out, access to an FTP server via Windows Explorer will always show `ftp:` at the beginning of the address, while SMB resources begin with \\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested earlier a simple distinguishing proceedure is in the way you type the address:

For example, when accessing ftp server, usually `ftp://server ip` , see below

[image: a].

And smb share `\\server ip`:

[image]

I have a rather lame way to differentiate between these,based on the way they function. It seems ftp has less Windows explorer integration features (e.f edit, open with etc) compared to smb:

[image] [image]

Comment: One is a network location which can be mounted.  The other is a ftp connection, which cannot be mounted, and contains `ftp:\\` instead of the network path to the device `\\devicename` seems pretty obvious to me ;$

Comment: @Ramhound pretty much so, can you please give a trick on how to differentiate these, not merely their definitions

Comment: *I just did.*  The icon(s) are also different.